# Keyword monitoring in log file in Windows Server

Tags: windows, logging, vbscript, monitoring, tail

I want to monitor a log(txt) file in Windows server and want to execute a script (to stop a windows service) on some keyword when it comes up in the log.

Is there any tool or script that can achieve this task? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PA Server Monitor's [Log File Monitor](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/sm_5_2/monitor_log_file.aspx) can do exactly that.

Comment: Do you know if there are any free tools available?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a schedule task every 5 mins and do this.

```
findstr /c:"[Fonts]" c:\windows\win.ini

If errorlevel = 1 goto :eof

sc start servicename
```

For help (read the Dos 6.22 reference for Find for exit codes [1 found, 2 not found, 3 error]) and type

```
findstr /?
schtasks /?
```